# Laptop shuts down upon waking up from suspend

Tags: drivers, graphics, shutdown

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile v5505 with the following configuration:

- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5750 2.00GHz
- Graphics card(integrated): Intel 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2

Other things pretty much standard.

Now after putting my laptop to sleep (by closing the lid) or hibernating, when I wake it up (by opening the lid) four things happen:

- Laptop login window is shown (normal behavior) - 10% of time
- Laptop suddenly shut downs for no reason - 30% of time
- When Ubuntu goes into desktop screen all icons or windows are blurred or screwed - 30% of time
- Black screen is shown (it doesn't disappear by moving the mouse) and I need to manually shut down the laptop - 30% of time

What I believe this is caused by drivers for my integrated graphics card, but there is nothing in "Additional Drivers". I hope there are some solutions for this crazy problem which makes my laptop not usable at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've found on bugs.launchpad.net. Seems like bugs 3 and bugs 4 are already reported here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel